# Mongo DB: How to embed documents from child collection to parent when MongoDB version is 4.2?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

2 `MongoDB` collection that I have:

`Categories`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6044ad2973d61b6452d46391"),
    "name" : "Category 1"
}
```

and `Products`:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6044ad6673d61b6452d463bd"),
    "name" : "Product 1",
    "categoryId" : "6044ad2973d61b6452d46391"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6044ad8173d61b6452d463c6"),
    "name" : "Product 2",
    "categoryId" : "6044ad2973d61b6452d46391"
}
```

On the local PC I have got the latest version of `MongoDB` installed (`>4.4`), that why to embed documents from `Products` collection to `Categories` I need to write a quite trivial and simple script:

```
db.getCollection('categories').aggregate([

{$match: {}}, 

{$addFields:{
    idStr: {$toString: "$_id"}
    }},
    
    {
        $lookup: {
             from: "products",
             localField: "idStr",
             foreignField: "categoryId",
             as: "products"
            }
        },
        
        {$project:{
            idStr: 0}},
            
            {$merge:
                {
                    into: "categories",
                    on:"_id" 
                    }}
])
```

The problem appears when I use `MongoDB` version `4.2` due to the following limitation for the `$merge` stage:

> Versions of MongoDB prior to 4.4 did not allow $merge to output to the
> same collection as the collection being aggregated.

So, the question is: how to rewrite the existing query to have a possibility execute in for version `4.2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/): Takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection. The `$out` operator must be the last stage in the pipeline.

Try this:

```js
db.categories.aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    {
        $addFields: {
            idStr: { $toString: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            localField: "idStr",
            foreignField: "categoryId",
            as: "products"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { idStr: 0 }
    },
    {
        $out: "categories"
    }
]);
```

Note: Be careful with the `$match` stage since you will loose all those documents not matching the conditions.